# Python passing object as arg in minimize()

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to pass object as extra argument to scipy.optimize.minimize() but it says can't pass object

```
  def myfun(C,gamma,deg,mysvc):
    from sklearn import cross_validation
    if(mysvc.kernel=="linear"):
       mysvc.C=C
    elif(mysvc.kernel=="rbf" or mysvc.kernel=="sigmoid"):
       mysvc.C=C
       myscv.gamma=gamma
    else: 
       mysvc.deg=deg
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(mysvc,cross[:,:95], cross[:,96], cv=5)
    return mean(scores) 


  from scipy import optimize  
  for mysvc in [gsn,ply,sig,lin]:
    C,gamma,deg=sp.optimize.minimize(fun=myfun,x0=asarray([1,.5,3]),args=(mysvc))
    print [C,gamma,deg]
```

Is the tupule not flexible?? mysvc is an object of class SVC from sklearn
I get the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",  line 540, in runfile
 execfile(filename, namespace)
 File "C:/Users/sriramana/svm.py", line 43, in <module>
 C,gamma,deg=sp.optimize.minimize(fun=myfun,x0=asarray([1,.5,3]),args=(mysvc))
 File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 372, in minimize
 return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
 File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 832, in  _minimize_bfgs
 gfk = myfprime(x0)
 File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 281, in  function_wrapper
 return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
 File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 604, in approx_fprime
 f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
 File "e:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 281, in function_wrapper
 return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
 TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "SVC") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`args=(mysvc)` needs a comma to make a tuple: `args=(mysvc,)`

[Tutorial 5.3. Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

> a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.

Comment: Yup that worked!! but now it says "myfun() takes exactly 4 args but only 2 given"..???

Comment: @user3443615 `myfun` should take the arguments `C,gamma,deg` as a single array, I think.

Comment: I have a problem ,I am getting the same initial arguments as result whatever I pass as initial value

Comment: @user3443615 That could be the subject of another question.